# Check if two comma separated lists have at least one common part

Tags: strings

I am trying to do conditional exports based on the jobname.

What I've got so far:

```
\def\defaultexport#1{\gdef\@defaultexport{#1}}
\newcommand\setdefaultexport[2][main]{
  \edef\@jobnameextracted{\jobname}
  \def\@jobnamedefault{#1}
  \@onelevel@sanitize\@jobnamedefault
  \ifx\@jobnameextracted\@jobnamedefault%
    \defaultexport{#2}
  \else
    \defaultexport{\jobname}
  \fi
}
```

in this way, I can set default exports using

```
\setdefaultexport[myfilename]{targetA,targetB}
```

and if a jobname is set (e.g. `--jobname=targetC`), it uses the jobname.

now I need a command that prints the content if at least one of its list is in the above given list:

```
\printcond{targetB,targetD}{
My Text Block
}
```

i tried doing so using `\readlist`, however, it seems not to work

```
\newcommand\printcond[2]{
  \setsepchar{,}
  \readlist*\exporttargets{\@defaultexport}
   %if #1 has at least one common item with \exporttargets
   % -> Print #2
   % else do nothing
}
```

seems not to split the list.

Comment: It would help to have a full MWE, rather than just snippets.  Also, `\printcond` takes two arguments and seems to do nothing with them.

Comment: Not really clear. Please be more specific describing some use cases and the expected output. What role has `main`? What's the purpose of the optional argument in `\setdefaultexport`?

Comment: if i use no jobname, latexmk uses the filename as jobname. If the jobname is the filename, I want to use the defaults, defined in `\setdefaultexport`

Comment: That clarifies nothing, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing lists is straightforward:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\comparelists[2]{%
  \def\itemmatch{F}%
  \foreachitem\z\in#1[]{%
    \foreachitem\zz\in#2[]{%
      \ifx\z\zz\def\itemmatch{T}\fi%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\listA{xyz, pdq, latex, junk}
\readlist*\listB{xabc, def, pdq}
\readlist*\listC{ghi, jk, lmnop}

\comparelists\listA\listB: \itemmatch

\comparelists\listA\listC: \itemmatch
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not exactly clear, without an MWE from the OP what he is attempting.  However, I would note that `\setdefaultexport[myfilename]{targetA,targetB}` defines `\@defaultexport` as literally, `\jobname`.

Thus, `\readlist*\exporttargets{\@defaultexport}` should expand *exactly once* `\jobname` and search that as a comma-separated list.